# Limiting probability question

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence, co.combinatorics

Let $X$ denote an $m\times n$ matrix and suppose that each value $x_{ij}$ is an integer that is selected uniformly at random from ${1,\dots,n}$, independently of all other values.  If we fix $m$ and take the limit as $n\to\infty$, what is the probability that there exists a number that is contained in all $m$ rows of $X$?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? This does not seem appropriate for MO.

Comment: Not homework, but I'm happy to post to stackexchange if that's the majority opinion.

Comment: A confession: I actually don't know anything about probability, which is why I didn't downvote or vote to close. This looks, though, like it is not research-level, which is what this site is for. (Also, if you post to MSE, you should give some motivation for this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

By approximate independence between the $n$ numbers (and complete independence among the rows for a fixed number), the probability is approximately
$$1-(1-(1/e)^m)^n\rightarrow 1.$$

Comment: Thanks, I gather that the "approximate independence" assumption is used to justify the $()^n$ expression.  Is there a way to make that argument more rigorous?  I've googled "approximate independence", "almost independent", et cetera, but can't seem to find a body of literature that would help in justifying that.

Comment: Could try to replace "is approximately" by "is $\ge $" but it might become a long computation.